# C++ File-stream Vector Input

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am currently working in c++. My goal is to be able to implement the A* algorithm, through a series of steps I plan to be able to store, and list the shortest path from Point A to Point B.

My program will take in a command-line argument which will be a file to read in. The purpose of giving the program a file t read in is that each file is its own "grid" for A* to process. The format for the grid file is as follows:

Num 1 = WIDTH and then Num 2 = HEIGHT

o = start

* = finish

. = passable node

# = impassable wall

So an example grid, let's call it "Grid1", would be:

```
8 5 
o......#
......##
.....###
....####
.......*
```

So to process this, when you run the program you would pass in "Grid1".
From here, I plan to create a filestream and read in each character into a 2D Array/Vector to attempt to recreate the grid so I can have positions. For example, in "Grid1" the character "o" would be at position [0][0] in a Array/Vector. My attempted implementation is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    //Checking for CLA
    if( argc < 1 ) 
    {   
    cout << "Program must take atleast <1> arguments!" << endl << "1) File to read  2) OPTIONAL: Type of search" << endl;
}   

//CLA #1 is the file containing GRID to be read in
string gridTBO = argv[1];

//Start new filestream and open grid file for reading
ofstream gridFile;
gridFile.open( gridTBO );  

//Check to make sure we can even open the file before proceeding
if( gridFile.is_open() )
{   
//To store grid data
vector<string> grid;
grid[0][0].push_back("Hello");
cout << grid[0][0]; 

}
```

However, in regards to my "push_back", it seems that I am not able to print out or throw the data into the vector. I would primarily want each index such as [0][0] [0][1] [0][2] to hold each individual character in order to recreate a grid like the one I pass in.

I am not quite sure what I am doing incorrectly as I am fairly inexperienced using vectors, however, the code for pushing data into the grid is purely for testing purposes. Once I am able to parse some data into the vector, I would then like to automate it with a loop and have "getline" or a similar function grab the data for me.

So my main questions are:
1) Why is my push_back and print out failing?
2) How would I read in char by char with a loop to prevent me from manually putting data in?

The error I receive on run-time is:
**Segmentation Fault(core dump)**

Thank you everyone in advance for your assistance and knowledge!

Comment: No self-respecting C++ compiler will compile `grid[0][0].push_back("Hello");` when `grid` is, allegedly, a `std::vector<string>`, without barking very loudly. Your question claims that you compiled this, and it's crashing at run time. This is obviously not the real code that was compiled, if so, but the shown code in this question is fantasy code. If you'd like real answers to a real question, it is necessary to show real code, as a [mcve], instead of fantasy code. Furthermore, the long-winded introduction, in this question, has nothing to do with anything, and is just a waste of reading time.

Comment: My apologies, that is in fact my code and I was simply giving an introduction into why I am using the vector in the first place. I hope that in the future I will be able to ask better questions, I apologize again for whatever I did incorrectly, I am simply trying to learn why things are and are not working. I am relatively new to using C++ vectors and when you refer to it being absolutely wrong, that's exactly my question, I don't understand why that would be so "absurd" and "fantastical"

Comment: The absurdity is you claim a seg fault, something that can only occur at runtime, from code that cannot be compiled and thus cannot run. We cannot tell you what caused the segfault because according to the provided information it cannot happen at all. That is absurd.

Comment: Well thank you for the information, I'll just keep tinkering with it I suppose, hopefully I do something that makes it stop giving me core dumps. I assume since one user mentioned the absurdity of calling print on [0][0], despite my ability to compile, that is probably what I need to change.

Comment: Truly again, I apologize to you all. It was clearly a mistake to ask my question, I can assure you I am not related to some banned users revenge posting with "absurd" and "bogus" posts. I am a student in university trying to learn more about C++ as that is the language our intro to advanced coding classes teach. I wish I knew more about what I was doing so I could have angered you less, again, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ofstream` is for output file. Use `ifstream` for reading the file.

```
vector<string> grid;
```

`vector<string>` will work in your case. But it's easier to create a 2-D array of vector with `vector<vector<char>>`, then you access `grid[x][y]`

Unlike arrays, vectors don't have any elements when they are created, so there is no valid `grid[x][y]` or `grid[x]` until you add something to it.

Try this code instead:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");

    vector<vector<char>> grid;

    int row = 0;
    string line;
    while(fin >> line)
    {
        grid.resize(row + 1);
        for(auto c : line)
            grid[row].push_back(c);
        row++;
    }

    for(auto row_vector : grid)
    {
        for(auto e : row_vector)
            cout << e;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barmak, I greatly appreciate your assistance. I was completely lost on why my I couldn't manpulate the vector the way I wanted but I have since switched ofstream to ifstream and followed a similar guideline from your advice. I think I understand a little more about how to complete my goal thanks to your knowledge!

Comment: One last question, if you don't mind. What exactly is "row+1" doing?

Comment: @Illu: grid.resize(row+1) increases the size of the vector to row + 1. If row == 0, then you need the size of the vector to be 0 + 1, that is, 1, to store the row. If row == 1, you have rows 0 and 1 to store, hence the size needs to be 1 + 1, that is, 2, and so on.

Comment: Note that resize adds new elements to the vector until it reaches the specified size. These new elements must be either given or left to the default constructor of their type to create them. Here the elements are of type vector<char>, so an empty vector<char> is created at the end of grid with this command. Then comes a loop over c to add the characters in line to grid[row] one by one.